How do I use mido with python in callback mode
I am trying to use mido to capture MIDI in callback mode, and it just doesn't work. I can poll the same input no problem. Tried on Linux 24.04 and Windows 10, Python 3.12 and 3.13. The rtmidi equivalent works, but the callback in mido refuses to fire. What am doing wrong?
This is my code:
import time

innames = mido.get_input_names()

def input_callback():
    print("MESSAGE RECEIVED")

port_in = None
for n in innames:
    if n.startswith("USB"):
        port_in = mido.open_input(n, callback=input_callback)


if port_in != None:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)```


